# How to run all iterations of for loop and then fail at the end?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script which pushes data to another system. If it cannot push data for whatever reason then it will exit with non-zero status code otherwise it will not.

I am using my python script in my below shell script.

```
export NAME="${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME//\//-}-1${CI_PIPELINE_IID}"
for environment in dev stage; do
  FILE_NAME="${NAME}-${environment}.tgz";
  python helper.py push ${environment} master ${FILE_NAME};
  python helper.py push ${environment} slave ${FILE_NAME};
done
```

As of now if any one python line fails for any one environment then it doesn't move forward to the next iteration at all (or if first python line fails then it doesn't run second python line) but I want to run all iterations of my for loop and also run second python line if first one fails for whatever reason.

Is there any way I can run all iterations of my for loop irrespective of whether my python script fails for any environment or not and also run second python line if previous one fail and then at the end it should fail if exit status code is non-zero (after running everything) after running everything.

Is this possible to do? Basically somehow I need to store exit code of all the possible python line executions (total 4) and then exit at the end later on.

Comment: I don't see any code that makes it stop if there's a failure.

Comment: @BurntIce There's no `quit` function in `bash`.

Comment: It's in Python script where I use `exit 1` if I cannot push data to another system and that exit 1 fails my script and it doesn't move forward. @Barmar

Comment: Why would `exit 1` fail your script? Do you use `set -e` earlier?

Comment: No I don't have `set -e`. This script is part of gitlab yml file where I run series of script to perform operations.

Comment: Is there any way to run my python lines for all four times irrespective of status code and then fail at the end if any one returned non zero status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional operator to set a variable.

```
failed=false
for environment in dev stage; do
  FILE_NAME="${NAME}-${environment}.tgz";
  python helper.py push ${environment} master "${FILE_NAME}" || failed=true
  python helper.py push ${environment} slave "${FILE_NAME}" || failed=true
done
if [ "$failed" = true ]
then
  exit 1
fi
```

BTW, you probably don't need to export `NAME`. Exporting is only needed if a child process uses the variable, not for variables uses within the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically somehow I need to store exit code of all the possible python line

Try this

```
declare -A result
for env in dev stage; do
  FILE_NAME="$NAME-$env.tgz"
  python helper.py push "$env" master "$FILE_NAME"; result["$FILE_NAME"]=$?
  python helper.py push "$env" slave  "$FILE_NAME"; result["$FILE_NAME"]=$?
done

For key in ${!result[@]}; do
    echo "Exit code for $key is: ${result[$key]}"
    ((err+=${result[$key]}))
done

exit $err
```